# "Add" button in Gnome Printers greyed out

Tags: cups

The symptoms of the issue:

- you have the **"Add..."** button in the Gnome Printers window **greyed out**
- you add a printer through the CUPS Web UI ([localhost:631](http://localhost:631/)) but when you open Gnome Printers or run `lpstat -a` under your **normal user**, the printer **is not** listed

  - but when you run `lpstat -a` under **root**, the printer **is** listed

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Removing `ServerName` from the ~/.cups/client.conf file.

**Details:** I had `ServerName <URL>` set in ~/.cups/client.conf for my normal user. So for my normal user (not root) the CUPS client (which provides the available printers e.g. to Gnome Printers) was trying to get printers from the CUPS server running on `<URL>`. Not from my localhost CUPS server, which was providing the printer I've added through the CUPS Web UI.